# Android: Option menu like on Motorola Gallery app?

Tags: android, add-on

I'd like to design the option menus of my new app similar to the option menu in Motorola Gallery app. When you click on an album, the screen darkens, and on the bottom right corner, the option menu buttons scroll up.

Do you know any add-on, library or whatever to achieve such behaviour or do I have to program it by my own (that means darkening the screen, do animations on the buttons,...)

[image: Gallery app]

Comment: Asking for off-site resources is considered to be [off-topic for Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: It doesn't have to a be exactly a library or so, maybe it can be achieved with Android's functionality as well?

Comment: The Design Support library's FAB does not support the floating action menu (FAM) pattern AFAIK. That's your animated set of buttons rising up from the FAB. In terms of darkening the screen, one way to do that is a `View` with a translucent background, layered over top of the content but below the FAB/FAM.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in this way.

First create layout of that window

```
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"    
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#7F000000">
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="close"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

In OnClickListner method of item (say album) you can write code to open up dialog

```
listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
dialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog);
        dialog.show();
        Button close = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.close);
        close.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
```

You can manage transparency of window by changing apha value of background attribute. Add different buttons as per your requirement